# What is the right place for setRequestedOrientation & android:screenOrientation="landscape" does not work

Tags: android, android-manifest, landscape

I'm trying to build an app which runs only in landscape mode. During my research I found some really nice tips on how to fulfil it. The first one is to include: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` in onCreate() method right after `setContentView(R.layout.activityName);` and it actually works, however some other sources claim that this sentence must be included before `setContentView(R.layout.activityName);`and not surprisingly it also works. So now I am wondering which practice is better and is there are any difference at all?

The other thing is that I also read that you should include android:screenOrientation="landscape" in the project's manifest file to ensure that the app will run in landscape mode. Nevertheless, I think this sentence isn't usefull at all. I tried to run my app with this sentence included and without this sentence and I didn't notice any difference - both times I was able to switch to portrait mode (I am targeting API 16 and higher).

So, can anyone explain what's the best practice to ensure that your app runs only in landscape mode?

Comment: The `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` should work, but for API 13+ [you should also declare the "screenSize" configuration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).